# Concatenate and Mutate Factors R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
structure(list(Race = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 
5L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Black or African American", 
"Black or African American,White or Caucasian", "East Asian", 
"East Asian,Pacific Islander", "Hispanic or Latino/a", "Other", 
"Pacific Islander", "South Asian", "White or Caucasian", "White or Caucasian,Hispanic or Latino/a", 
"White or Caucasian,Middle Eastern"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

I'm comparing multiple races on census data. What I'd like to do is create a new variable saying if the person is a minority or not based on if that row contains anything other than ONLY "White or Caucasian". So if someone lists themselves as "Pacific Islander" they will be listed as "Minority" in the new variable. If they are listed as only "White or Caucasian" they will be "Majority". Notice that some of these cells have a combination of races including "White or Caucasian" plus some other race. Anyone with more than one race should still be considered "Minority"

Comment: You can list your conditions and use `ifelse` along with `grep` to add the new column

Comment: I figured I'd use grep, but does grep have an argument that allows you to match entire cell contents instead of only part of it?

Comment: yes, you can surround your pattern with ^ and $, Also read out parameters to `grep`

Comment: Do you even need `grep` here?  If you are only concerned with only 'White or Caucasian' can you not simply do something like (I'm including dplyr here since your tag is mutate) `your.df <- your.df %>% mutate(Race2=ifelse(Race=='White or Caucasian','Majority','Minority')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
df %>% mutate(new_var = ifelse(Race=="White or Caucasian","Majority","Minority"))
```

Comment: Great! Out of curiosity, can you also combine this with an OR expression like if "White or Caucasian" OR(|) "East Asian" then this row will be "Majority" else "Minority

Comment: @762 you could do `ifelse(Race %in% c("White or Caucasian","East Asian"),...`